# Time interval query

Tags: sql

I would like to make a query to get data (PasssportNumber) have a BoarderCrossing in specific time interval. I have found an almost right answer here but it didn't give solution for me when the first time of the interval greater than the second.

```
BorderCrossingID  PassportNumber    BorderCrossingDateTime
1                    ER-2222        2019-01-07 22:11:12.000
2                    ER-2222        2019-01-07 23:11:12.000
3                    KL-5233        2018-10-03 17:10:39.000
130                  FF-4444        2019-01-08 11:11:11.000
5                    ER-1111         NULL
6                    KL-5686         NULL
7                    ER-1111         NULL
8                    KL-5235         NULL
9                    QW-5656         NULL
160                  NN-4444       2019-01-30 12:51:19.000
161                  JJ-8911       2019-02-25 14:26:08.000
163                  FG-7878       2019-02-28 11:00:53.113
165                  NN-4444       2018-02-28 12:51:19.000
166                  GG-4545       2019-02-28 13:38:08.233
167                  FF-9876       2019-02-28 14:12:26.000
168                  FG-4587       2019-03-12 15:56:45.303
169                  ZZ-2332       2019-03-13 09:18:11.543
170                  FR-0120       2019-03-14 14:40:32.313
171                  FG-0120       2019-03-14 14:41:07.703
172                  FF-0012       2019-03-14 05:43:16.623
173                  FF-0012       2019-03-14 14:43:26.833
178                  TU-0140       2019-03-18 00:15:10.000
179                  IU-0140       2019-03-18 23:15:10.000
```

The code below works right perfectly when the first time is the smaller one. If the OR is changed to AND the query works reverse mode (The first time can be the greater but the result going to be false when the second is the greater one)

```
SELECT PassportName
       FROM Passports
       EXCEPT
       SELECT BorderCrossingDateTime
       FROM Passports
       WHERE BorderCrossingDateTime IS NULL OR CONVERT(TIME, BorderCrossingDateTime) < '23:00' OR CONVERT(TIME, BorderCrossingDateTime) > '23:59'
```

I would like to have a solution which can work with every time possibilities. 
In c# I used TimeSpan to avoid this problem.

Result Shoud be below using the query I want to implement:

```
    SELECT PassportName
           FROM Passports
           EXCEPT
           SELECT BorderCrossingDateTime
           FROM Passports
           WHERE BorderCrossingDateTime IS NULL OR CONVERT(TIME, BorderCrossingDateTime) < '23:00' OR CONVERT(TIME, BorderCrossingDateTime) > '01:00'

PassportNumber
ER-2222
TU-0140
IU-0140
```

Comment: Can you please provide the database name, some sample data and your expected output?

Comment: I have made a small complementation.

Comment: I have checked your first 5 passport number from the expected output list and they are not available in your sample data. And also please make clear the Time Range where from you wants to pick records. You current condition on time is not clear.

Comment: The two times are set by the user. Parameters got from a WinForm. I have changed the Data, now it is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Your query is almost correct. You have just Greater and Less that issue in your query. Please check the correct ans in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken:

- Between 10:00 and 20:00 means >= 10:00 **and** < 20:00
- Between 20:00 and 10:00 means >= 20:00 **or** < 10:00

The query:

```
select passportname
from (select passports.*, convert(time, bordercrossingdatetime) as tm from passports) p
where (@start < @end and tm >= @start and tm < @end)
   or (@start > @end and (tm >= @start or tm < @end));
```

Comment: I made the parts of your query separately a lot of times. I dont know why but I didn't put them together. Thank you! You opened my yes! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this-

```
SELECT PassportNumber
FROM Passports
WHERE CONVERT(TIME, BorderCrossingDateTime) > '23:00' 
OR CONVERT(TIME, BorderCrossingDateTime) < '01:00'
```

Output-

```
ER-2222
TU-0140
IU-0140
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort too. Sorry to say but it does not work if the first number is smaller than the second.